# SearchKit refuses to open index after crashes

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I'm experimenting with OS X's SearchKit framework to provide full text indexing of the users data.

I'm keeping the index database open for the entire life time of the app. I assume there might be a significant overhead for repeatedly opening and closing the index database for each tiny edit the user makes, especially once the index has reached a considerable size (1 GByte+).

However, every time the app crashes or I kill it via Xcode, SearchKit refuses to open the index file, even when the index wasn't altered during the session. SKIndexOpenWithURL simply returns NULL. In a production environment, I would need to rebuild the complete index a this point. I don't think users would appreciate this behavior.

Anybody here knows how to best work around this issue? Is opening the index only for updates or searches the way to go?